# How to enable system title bar in Chrome to make it visible on every workspace?

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome

Starting two days ago (9/22/21) on both of my Kubuntu machines Chrome no longer displays system title bars and borders. The option in settings is enabled. Disable/re-enable/reboot hasn't fixed it. All other applications display this correctly.

[image: chrome]

My machines are both Kubuntu. lsb_release -a says Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. Chrome is 94.0.4606.61.

I've received no responses on the KDE-users list. On the Gentoo list the one person who responded said he also didn't have the system title bar but when he reenabled the feature and for him it works.

Using the system title bar allows Chrome to be pinned to all virtual desktops which I need for media. In the immediate term I'm using Firefox for that purpose but would prefer to use Chrome.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Chrome with Appearance & Fix setting]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Also check if the same issue is present in Chromium.

Comment: Happy to but don't know how. Will research or tell me how to embed a png file.

Comment: The following points to a screenshot. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-GU-VzJyFiB0wmzjTeOD9Yf37rJQCzQU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can edit to upload images (I did that for you). This is most likely due to the new CSD in chrome, which does not integrate very well with KDE (See https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/08/chrome-finally-fixes-csd-issues-on-linux). I will try to log in to my KDE desktop and try to find a fix.

Comment: Same problem in GNOME too. Possibly a new bug in Chrome.

Comment: This problem seem to have been solved in Version 95.0.4638.54 (Official Build) (64-bit) of Chrome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per Google this is a [new issue](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/127138612/use-system-title-bar-and-borders-broken-in-google-chrome-94-please-repair?hl=en) from 94

From [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/pgm1n9/chrome_title_bar/), here is a (temporary) quick fix:

- Ensure that "Use system title bar and borders" is set
- Go to chrome://flags
- Find the "use-ozone-platform" setting and change it from "default" to "disabled"
- Relaunch Chrome

Comment: The same problem persists in the newly released 94.0.4606.71 version of Chrome. The workaround given in this answer works though.

Comment: This problem was solved in version 95.

Answer (score 8):

### Solution

Right click on the Chrome title bar, and check Use system title bars and borders (I tested this on Chromium in XFCE, but it should work on Chrome in KDE too).

[image: solution]
 <sup>Before enabling title bar</sup>

Now the title bar is there, and you can make it visible in every workspace.

[image: after]
 <sup>After enabling title bar</sup>

---

### Background

Chrome is a GTK app. Like most other GTK apps it switched to CSD (client side decoration) in the recently released version 94. Now it draws its own title bar, instead of using the title bar provided by KDE Plasma.

Comment: I am using GNOME and the same problem mentioned in the Question is present here too, after the recent upgrade of Chrome. **You cannot right click on the title bar and select "Always on Visible Workspace".** Your answer does not make any difference in this respect.

Comment: We need something like the one shown on this screenshot https://imgur.com/a/0l9FAuE (taken using Firefox).

Comment: Prior to asking the questions I was already set to use GTK+ and the original post said the  use system title bars didn't work. So far help for me either. PLEASE NOTE: A 'theme' is NOT a title bar. The CLient Side Decoration comment seems appropriate as to the possible cause of the problem though

Comment: It didn't work for me on Kubuntu but one Gentoo use said he found turning on the ozone experimental option under chrome://flags worked for him. Anyone reading might try that out.

Comment: By updated answer to you mean what looks like the secondary pulldown with the Always on Visible Workspace option? I always had the Use system title bar turned on. In your second screen shot you have the system title bar but I do not see that here on Chrome.

Comment: I did find one barely acceptable solution for KDE. In the Window Management section of System Settings there is a Window Rules entry for google-chrome. In the Appearances  & fixes section if I set "No titlebar and frame" to 'Do Not Effect" then I do get a title bar but Chrome is sort of suspended inside a window with transparent space around it. Will try and post a screenshot.

Comment: I'm sorry. I guess I'm just stupid. I THINK what you are saying in your post with the two screenshots is that in the first you do not have a system title bar, you right click the tab session and turn on the option. In the second screenshot you are showing that you have the system title bar and that the title bar has a menu. What I am saying is that I already have the option you chose turned on but I do NOT get the system title bar that you show in the second screenshot.

Comment: @LGTrader It works for me in Chromium, after turning on that option. Consider switching to Chromium, the experience is very similar.

Comment: This answer does not work with Chrome version 94.0.4606.61 on Xubuntu. I see the "Use system title bar and borders" setting when right-clicking on the top bar, and can turn the setting on (a checkmark is displayed to the left of the setting title), but this does not add the system title bar nor borders, even after restarting the browser.

Comment: @TeemuLeisti It works for me in Chromium 94.0.4606.54. Maybe it would work in the next version of Chrome, as suggested in the other answer.

Comment: This worked for ms-edge on Archlinux + KDE. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome beta works OK so hopfully when it migrates to stable this fault will be gone.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

The setting can be easily changed by right-click on the title bar.
If not, here is another way:

The setting is controlled by a boolean `custom_chrome_frame` in `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences`.

If it is `false`, then the system title bar will be used; if is `true`, it is customed by the browser. I suggest that before changing the boolean, the browser should be closed, otherwise the file may be modified by the browser.

It works for chrome (`~/.config/google-chrome`), chromium (`~/.config/chromium`), and MS edge (`~/.config/microsoft-edge`). And it seems to be the only way to bring the custom title bar back.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is specifically for KDE but I suspect other desktop environments has similar capabilities.

SystemSettings->Shortcuts->KWin->Keep Window on All Desktop

and program it to something. I chose Meta+a (Windows key and a for 'all')

It appears to work for all app and it's a toggle.